# Google Sheets conditional formatting for Max value that meets a second condition

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, conditional-formatting

I'm working with a baseball statistics spreadsheet in Google Sheets, and I want to highlight the maximum value in my batting average column, but only if that value is for a player who has satisfied the proper criteria to qualify as a leader — their plate appearances must be greater than or equal to the maximum number of games played in the Games Played Column multiplied by 2.1.

In my sheet, Column B=Games Played, Column E=Plate Appearances, Column O=Batting Average.

I think I've got the logic to isolate the games played and plate appearance condition:

```
$E:$E>=max(D2:D1000)*2.1
```

But I don't know how to show *only* the max value of that subset. I tried an AND function:

```
=AND($E:$E>=max(D2:D1000)*2.1)+($O:$O=max(O:O))
```

...but that gets everyone who meets that condition *and* the current max in that column.

I then tried to write logic to show the max IF:

```
=max(O2:O100)=IF($E:$E>=max(D2:D1000)*2.1)
```

...but I think this probably will make me look silly because I'm only just starting to learn how to do this! :)

Would be so appreciative of your help.

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: Sure thing. Here's a link to an editable copy (not my main sheet since I'll delete this after) but it has the same formatting and data that I'm working with now: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bTnCa0lx6MHvTHBkECsjtNcfcZ1yI_boIOHfHEPAeiE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=AND(E2>=MAX(D2:D)*2.1,O2=MAX(O2:O),O2<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MAX(IF(E$2:E>=MAX(D$2:D)*2.1, O$2:O)))
```

[image: 0]